# How to create an execve() child process with the right tty settings to run 'vi' yet still redirect IO back to the parent process?

Tags: linux, io-redirection, tty, fork

How do I get a forked, `execve()` child process that can run 'vi', etc. and redirect all IO to the parent process?

I'm trying to pass shells through from an embedded Linux process to the PC software interface connected over the network. The IO for the shell process is packaged into app-specific messages for network transport over our existing protocol.

First I was just redirecting IO using simply `pipe2()`, `fork()`, `dup2()`, and `execve()`. This didn't give me a tty on the remote side, so `screen`, etc. didn't work.

Now I'm using `forkpty`, and `screen` mostly works, but many many other don't (`vi`, `stty`, etc). It appears the current problem is that the child process doesn't control the tty.

I've been experimenting with TIOCSCTTY, but haven't had much luck.

Here's more or less what I've got:

```
bool ExternalProcess::launch(...)
{
    ...

    winsize winSize;

    winSize.ws_col = 80;
    winSize.ws_row = 25;
    winSize.ws_xpixel = 10;
    winSize.ws_ypixel = 10;

    _pid = forkpty(&_stdin, NULL, NULL, &winSize);

    //ioctl(_stdin, TIOCNOTTY, NULL);

    if (!_pid && (_pid != -1))
    {
        // this is the child process
        char tty[4096];
        strncpy(tty, ttyname(STDIN_FILENO), sizeof(tty));
        tty[sizeof(tty)-1]=0;

        FILE* fp = fopen("debug.txt", "wt");    // no error checking - temporary test code
        fprintf(fp, "slave TTY %s", tty);

        //if (ioctl(_stdin, TIOCSCTTY, NULL) < 0)
        if (ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCSCTTY, NULL) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "ioctl() TIOCSCTTY %s\n", strerror(errno));
            fflush(fp);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(fp, "SET CONTROLLING TTY!");
            fflush(fp);
        }

        fclose(fp);

        // command, args, env populated elsewhere
        execve(command, args, env);

        ...

        // fail path
        _exit(-1);
        return false;
    }

    _stdout = _stdin;

    ...

    // enter select() loop reading/writing _stdin, _stdout
}
```

I am getting results in the debug file like:

```
slave TTY /dev/pts/5
SET CONTROLLING TTY!
```

but still many apps are failing with `tcsetattr()` errors. Am I right in thinking this is a controlling tty problem? How do I fix it?

**EDIT**

Minor correction. When I do the ioctl TIOCSCTTY on STDIN_FILENO, then it works as in the debug file above, but the IO redirection back to the parent process is disrupted.

**EDIT 2**

Okay, I'm starting to understand this better. Looking at the kernel source for the ioctl behind tcsetattr(), the processes I am calling are being sent SIGTTIN and SIGTTOU when trying to change the tty.

Only a foreground process can do that, and they're running as if they're background processes. I tried setting those signals to SIG_IGN after forking and before the execve(), but that didn't work. The semantics of this I understand, but it's safe in my redirection scenario for the execve()'d processes to act as if they're foreground processes. The question is... how to make it so? I will continue to search in the kernel code for clues.

Comment: Can't you use, e.g., `screen(1)` to do this?

Comment: As a workaround to use during this feature development, screen seems like it's working. We'd rather not give the users screen, though... we'll likely end up with some kind of restricted shell for end users. (for both security and UI complexity reasons)

Comment: You might be able to set up something using `screen(1)` and a restricted shell (e.g. `bash -r`, see `bash(1)`). Or, if desperate, pilfer the relevant code from `screen(1)` (but that is GPL, which might pose a problem depending on your needs; perhaps there is some BSD equivalent...).

Answer (score 1):

Ugh! It's bash, the shell I was calling with execve().

If it detects that stderr is not attached to a tty, then it enters this special mode where child processes cause SIGTTOU.

I found a mention of this problem [here.](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg03433.html)

When I stopped redirecting stderr away from the tty, then it now seems to work as planned.